# How to remove duplicate values ?for example if I have 5+10=15 then I don't want to print 10+5=15

Tags: python

```
arr1    =    [x for x in range (1,100) if all(x%y!=0 for y in range (2,x))]
arr2    =    arr1
arr3    =    [x for x in range (1,100) if x%2==0]
for i in arr3:
    for j in arr1:
        for k in arr2:
            if (j+k==i) and (j!=k):
                print (j,"+",k,"=",i)
```

I am getting output:

```
11 + 73 = 84
13 + 71 = 84
17 + 67 = 84
23 + 61 = 84
31 + 53 = 84
37 + 47 = 84
41 + 43 = 84
43 + 41 = 84
47 + 37 = 84
53 + 31 = 84
61 + 23 = 84
67 + 17 = 84
71 + 13 = 84
73 + 11 = 84
```

but I don't want the below portion as this is just a repeatation (only j and 
k position change).Only first 7 need to be printed.

```
43 + 41 = 84
47 + 37 = 84
53 + 31 = 84
61 + 23 = 84
67 + 17 = 84
71 + 13 = 84
73 + 11 = 84
```

Similarly for all the other even numbers.
Goldbach Conjecture --Every even number can be expressed as the sum of two 
prime numbers.There

Comment: You could but another clause that `j <= k`.

Comment: add the reverse of order of j, k in a tuple (k, j) to a set and then check before the print that (j, k) not in set for the next occurrence.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe store the results in a list and check whether its already printed or not...

```
arr1    =    [x for x in range (1,100) if all(x%y!=0 for y in range (2,x))]
arr2    =    arr1
arr3    =    [x for x in range (1,100) if x%2==0]
results = []
for i in arr3:
    for j in arr1:
        for k in arr2:
            if (j+k==i) and (j!=k) and i not in results:
                print (j,"+",k,"=",i)
                results.append(i)
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `arr2=arr1`

```
arr2 = arr1[:len(arr1) // 2)]
```

Should do the trick

Comment: `TypeError: slice indices must be integers or None or have an __index__ method`

Answer (score 0):

One simple change could be :

```
arr1    =    [x for x in range (1,100) if all(x%y!=0 for y in range (2,x))]
arr2    =    arr1
arr3    =    [x for x in range (1,100) if x%2==0]
for i in arr3:
    for j in arr1:
        for k in arr2:
            if (j+k==i) and (j<k): # change made here
                print (j,"+",k,"=",i)
```

If you look at your expected output vs your actual output, you'll see that what you want is all results where j is lower than k and not simply j different from k.

---

### Possible improvement

Also, I don't know much about python, but if it is as most languages, I think `arr2` is useless and you could save space doing the following :

```
arr1    =    [x for x in range (1,100) if all(x%y!=0 for y in range (2,x))]
arr3    =    [x for x in range (1,100) if x%2==0]
for i in arr3:
    for j in arr1:
        for k in arr1: # looking in the same array as j
            if (j+k==i) and (j<k):
                print (j,"+",k,"=",i)
```